# Input field read-only when it has value from database otherwise when it's null it should be editable

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I am new to this community, Your help is highly appreciated.
This is my line of code:

`<input type="text" class="form-control" id="fines" name="fines" placeholder = "Amount Penalty" required>`

My Javascript code:

````
$(document).ready (function(){



  if($(this).val()==""){
    $('#fines').attr('readOnly','false');
  }
  

});

</script>```




The thing that I want to achieve is that when clicking the field with no value it must be editable and if it has a value from the database it will remain a read-only field. 

Your help is highly appreciated thank you!!
````

Comment: Question needs more detail. Are you populating existing data on load?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this, as you are using a php variable for text input.

**Method 1:-**

```
<?php
    if( $row['fines'] == '' || $row['fines'] == NULL){
  echo '<input type="text" class="form-control" value="" id="fines" name="fines" placeholder = "Amount Penalty" required>';
    }
    else{
  echo '<input type="text" class="form-control" value="'.$row['fines'].'" id="fines" name="fines" placeholder = "Amount Penalty" readonly>';
    }
?>
```

**Method 2:-**

```
<?php
    if( $row['fines'] == '' || $row['fines'] == NULL){
      echo '<input type="text" class="form-control" value="" id="fines" name="fines" placeholder = "Amount Penalty" required>';
    }
    else{
      echo $row['fines'];//Show it as plain text, ez
    }
?>
```

**To Note :-** When you use `Method 1:-`  there are still chances of making that input text writable, just inspecting it and changing value would be easy enough for a user, I think `Method 2:-` is much better.